# How to create sitecollection programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I have used the following code buts its giving exception as System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. can anyone please correct

```
   try
    {
         SPWeb mySite = SPContext.Current.Web;
        SPWebCollection subSites = mySite.Webs;
        string currentTemplate = mySite.WebTemplate;

        string siteUrl = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
        string siteTitle = TextBox2.Text.ToString();
        string siteDescription = TextBox3.Text.ToString();

        subSites.Add(siteUrl, siteTitle, siteDescription, 1033,
           currentTemplate, true, false);

        lblMessage.Text = "Site created.";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Some error" + ex;
    }
```

Comment: Callstack at the moment of exception would be much more useful... and replace all `TextBoxX.Text` calls from sample with actual values that cause the exception.

Comment: its throwing exception in first line  SPWeb mySite = SPContext.Current.Web;

Comment: -1. Title of your question does not match current problem... and your sample contains unknown values (TextBoxX.Text) just for the sake of it...

Answer (score 2):

If you call this from a WPF or so you have to create the SPweb-object via the ServerURL.

instead of `SPWeb mySite = SPContext.Current.Web;`

try `SPWeb mySite = new SPSite("http://demo2010site")`

Answer (score 0):

You are running your code outside of SharePoint site. `SPContext.Current` is null in this case.

Without more details it is not possible to suggest any solutions for the exception.